# Magento 2 Enterprise - Can we use the page builder to create header/footer?

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, page-builder

We upgraded our shop to Magento 2 Enterprise. It comes with a page builder.

Can we use the page builder to create our whole site, including header, footer, category site, customer backend, login etc? Or does it only work with CMS sites / CMS blocks?